# SPA : how to avoid login page appearing when refresh page using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

I follow the below guide as you will see so when I refresh the page while loading Spiner running my current router will be login page and after loading Spiner finished then the dashboard page came back again, how can I solve this problem.
For the first time, I didn't use check the store inside a middleware that means when I refresh a page the system will logout.

route.js

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            middleware: [
                guest
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: () =>
            import ( /* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ '@/views/admin/Dashboard.vue'),
        meta: {
            middleware: [
                auth
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

middleware auth.js

```js
export default function auth ({ next, store }){
    if(!store.getters.auth){
        store.dispatch('isLogin');
    }

    if(!store.getters.auth){
        return next({
            // name: 'login'
            path: '/login',
        });
    }


    return next()
}
```

middleware guest.js

```js
export default function guest ({ next, store}){
    if(!store.getters.auth){
        store.dispatch('isLogin');
    }

    if(store.getters.auth){
        return next({
        //    name: 'dashboard'
            path: '/dashboard',
        })
    }


    return next()
}
```

index.js

```js
import routes from "./routes";
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // console.log("to, from, next", to, from, next, to.meta.middleware);

    if (!to.meta.middleware) {
        return next()
    }
    const middleware = to.meta.middleware
// console.log("middleware", middleware);
    const context = {
        to,
        from,
        next,
        store
    }
    return middleware[0]({
        ...context
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuex actions (like your `isLogin` action) are asynchronous so your user might not be logged in by the time you're checking `store.getters.auth` after you've dispatched `isLogin`.

You could use the "then" syntax for promises to ensure that your action has been completed before checking if the user is logged in:

```
export default async function auth({ next, store }) {
    if (!store.getters.auth) {
        store.dispatch("isLogin").then(_ => {
            if (!store.getters.auth) {
                return next({
                    path: "/login"
                });
            }

            return next();
        });
    }
}
```

And then call the middleware using the `await` keyword:

```
await middleware[0]({
        ...context
});
```